# OptaPlanner partitioned search strategy

Tags: optaplanner

I'm considering OptaPlanner's partitioned search feature because of a big scale VRPTW problem I need to deal with.

As far as I know a custom implementation of the SolutionPartitioner have to be implemented according to OptaPlanner's documentation. The example of a partitioner for a cloud balancing problem is straightforward, but I wonder how to partition planning etities in a VRPTW class problem.

Should I use a kind of a clustering algorithm in order to make a cluster based partitioning, or should I just divide input data like in the cloud balance example? Sometimes a lot of customers are placed on a relatively small area, but more workers are scheduled to service them. On the other hand there can be a service area where two clearly disjoint sub-areas are visible.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I haven't had time to do extensive benchmarking of specifically partitioning VRPTW myself (it's on my todo list), but the tooling is all there: just write those 3 different Partitioners and put them in optaplanner-benchmark on a number of datasets. Please do report here how that turns out :) *When we have data, let's go with the data. When all we have is opinions, let's go with mine.*

Comment: In fact I used another solver instance that works inside "splitWorkingSolution" and it dispatches customers to partitions using some constraints like initial load ratio constraint etc.